# Once a row is encountered, remove all rows within 40 days, then repeat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe, ordered by ID and Date :

df :

```
ID     Date
A      2019-01-02
A      2019-02-09
A      2019-02-20
A      2019-02-27
A      2019-03-16
A      2019-03-29
A      2019-04-17
A      2019-04-19
A      2019-05-26
A      2019-06-12
B      2017-01-01
B      ...
```

What I want is, when I encountered a row, to remove all rows with a date in the 40 days following, and repeat starting at the next (non-deleted) row I encounter. I want it for each ID.

For example with ID=A :

- I encounter the first row, date is `2019-01-02`. 40 days after is `2019-02-11`, so I remove all rows with Date strictly between those 2 dates. So second row is removed (Date = `2019-02-09`)
- Then, I look for the next row with `Date >= 2019-02-11` (`2019-02-11` being the end of the previous 40-days period). I find the 3rd row, with Date = `2019-02-20`. This is now the reference date taken, and 40 days after is `2019-04-01`. So 4th, 5th, 6th rows are removed
- ...

Note that my 40-days periods are starting when I encounter a new row and no 40-days period is currently active. Thus, those periods are not the same for all IDs.

This gives the following output dataset

```
ID     Date
A      2019-01-02
A      2019-02-20
A      2019-04-17
A      2019-06-12
B      2017-01-01
B      ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is vague, consider rephrasing

Comment: @Luke It's hard to put all details only in the title. That's why I put the example in the question, really detailing the problem. I can't find an appropriate title, not "too vague", I'm open for suggestions if you got any

Comment: So you're trying to ensure that _Your dataframe has only one instance of an ID within a period of 40 days_?

Comment: Yes, but the period is not fixed, it starts when I encounter a row (this row date being the start date of the 40-days period) AND no other 40-days period is active.

Comment: How do I know which line starts the period? (Wasn't clear in the question)

Comment: Once the previous period is ended, the first line you encounter, as shown in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop though the dataframe to create a filter

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

# create your dataframe "df" here...
# with columns "ID" and "Date"

# make sure your Date is a datetime field!
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

prev_id = None
prev_date = None
keep_rows = []

for _, row in df.iterrows():

    if row['ID'] == prev_id:
        delete = (row['Date'] - prev_date) < datetime.timedelta(days=40) 
        if delete:
            keep_rows.append(False)    
            continue
        
    keep_rows.append(True)
    prev_id = row['ID']
    prev_date = row['Date']
```

And filter your dataframe like this

```
df[keep_rows]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I was wondering if any answer with Pandas functions (and not iterrows) existed (because of the execution time), but this already helps me a lot

Comment: If you're running into execution time problems, you could use groupby and then loop over the Date column of each grouped dataframe to get the filter. I suspect that this might not be much faster, you'd have to write it and profile it. You could also try using iterrows over a dataframe that's limited to just the columns "ID" and "Date". And again, profile that if it's worth it

Comment: Final thought on this: You can replace iterrows with itertuples, which will also give you a speedup. For your tiny example, it's over 4 times faster. (I changed the solution to that)

Comment: I had some issues with itertuples, but it worked perfectly well with iterrows. Thanks a lot !